# Lua Recursion issue unexpected result

Tags: recursion, lua

I'm trying to figure out why this function is ignoring the middle most table? I'm overlooking something simple I assume.

Here's the code

```
tbl = {
    name = "first table";
    tbl = {
        name = "middle table";
        tbl = {
            name = "last table";
        };
    };
}

sayName = function(tbl)
    print(tbl.name)
    if tbl.tbl ~= nil then
        for _,v in pairs(tbl.tbl) do
            sayName(v)    
        end;
    end;
end;

sayName(tbl)
```

Output>

```
first table
last table
nil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you have a recursive structure, each table have 1 `name` and possibly a sub-table named `tbl`. So, I am not clear why would one use the `for` loop in these conditions.

```
tbl = {
  name = "first table",
  tbl = {
    name = "middle table",
    tbl = {
      name = "last table"
    }
  }
}

function PrintTable (Table)

  print("# Name", Table.name)
  
  local SubTable = Table.tbl

  if SubTable then
    return PrintTable(SubTable)
  end
  
end

PrintTable(tbl)
```

Will return:

```
# Name  first table
# Name  middle table
# Name  last table
```

Comment: what if i have multiple tables within a table. sorry does that make a difference? I'd like to loop through multiple sub tables. I'll update the question as well

Comment: This is part of a larger issue. I refactored my code to fit the actual issue but when I fixed it it also fixed the problem in the example. now I'm going to see if possibly I can use this knowledge to fix the problem i'm having in my project